# DLUX mirror built successful, but dlux/distribution-dlux folder is missing

Tags: opendaylight

I'm a NOOB to ODL.
I downloaded ODL Magnesium and able to run karaf.
I downloaded DLUX from the mirror (https://github.com/opendaylight/dlux) and it built successfully.
I'd like to install odl-dlux-core, but the dlux/distribution-dlux folder does not exist?
Thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you share error message?

Answer (score 0):

I manually copied the associated SNAPSHOT files to the system/org folder and was able to install dlux.

opendaylight-user@root>feature:list | grep dlux
features-dlux │ 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT │ x │ Started │ features-dlux │ features-dlux
odl-dlux-core │ 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT │ x │ Started │ odl-dlux-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT                                         │ Opendaylight dlux minimal feature

Now, when I navigate to http://localhost:8181/index.html, I get dark gray blank page. After inspection, I'd getting a 404 for
http://localhost:8181/src/common/authentification/auth.module.js

I am in fact missing a bunch of files;

```
topbar.module.js
common.general.module.js
core.module.js
navigation.module.js
login.module.js
layout.module.js
```

I'll investigate further as to where these archives should be avail.
Any advice is appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

After restarting ODL, I am now able to load the mentioned resources. However, my localhost:8181/index.html serves up a blank page and redirects to localhost:8181/index.html#/topology. I'm wondering if I need to install odl-dlux-topology?